# Как вычитывать данные с нуля?

Tags: php, sql-server

Есть скрипт который считывает данные с базы данных mssql. Но вот загвоздка...Вычитывает с единицы,а не с нуля. То есть если у меня 4 записи то считывает 2,3,4 ,а первую пропускает . Что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$serverName = "localhost, 1433"; 
$uid = "web_user";   
$pwd = "Gf45Rn27G";  
$databaseName = "plc_server"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd,"Database"=>$databaseName); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

if ($conn){
    echo "Подключение к серверу успешно!<br/>";

    // обработка запроса  
    $tsql = "SELECT SVG_NAME,PARAMETERS,TYPE_PARAMETERS FROM SVG_PARAMETERS  WHERE SVG_PAGE='1' and SVG_GROUP='1' and ENABLE='1' ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

    if( $stmt === false )  
        {  
            echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";  
        }  

    if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false)  
        {  
            echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";  
        } 

    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);    
     echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."<br>";  
     $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);    
     echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."<br>";  
}else{
    echo "Нет подключения к серверу. <br/>";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn); 

?>
```

Comment: Предположу, что дело в условии  WHERE SVG_PAGE='1' and SVG_GROUP='1' and ENABLE='1' Скорее всего запись под них не попала.

Comment: покажите записи, которые есть в БД и которые выбираются в результате запроса

Comment: Я уже просматривал этот вариант, с условием все нормально.В любом случае 1 строку пропускает точнее как бы нулевую

Comment: сбросил. Первые 4 записи

Comment: NVD_9,10,11,12.

Comment: `sqlsrv_fetch` фетчит первую запись, а `sqlsrv_fetch_array` начинает со второй.

Comment: То есть должно быть так ?  
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);    
     echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."<br>";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уберите все лишние фетчи

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql); 

if ($stmt === false) {
  die("Error in statement preparation/execution.\n");
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."<br>";  
}
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо , такая мелочь ,а не давала уснуть )